# main.chunk.js:1003 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, core

Приложение Asp.NET Core + React
Столкнулся с проблемой main.chunk.js:1003 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'
никак не могу решить

```
 services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
```

Comment: Может для начала собрать проект без разделения. Так сказать чтоб запустился проект. А затем шаг за шагом подгружать код

Comment: для этого мне нужно будет создать два раздельных проекта

Comment: Ну как то двигаться дальше надо. Просто кидать такого рода топики суда, это как поможет? Мы как должны вам помочь? Код у вас. И мы можем предложить вам пути решения проблемы. Решать вам сколько проектов нужно будет.

Comment: Я кинул его потому что похожая проблема уже есть на форуме и на нее есть ответ, мой же вопрос отличается одним символом в кавычках.

Comment: Возможно да. А если нет?

Comment: Если нет уже придется разделять)